# Javascript function is not working on dynamically added popup

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to excute this function on page load.

```
function myFunction() {
  var locker = document.querySelector('.onp-sl-signin-locker');
    var socialIcon = document.querySelector('.elementor-share-buttons--shape-circle');
  if (window.getComputedStyle(locker, null).display != "none") {
    socialIcon.style.display = "block";
  }
    else {
        socialIcon.style.display = "none";
    }
    console.log('Script load');
}
myFunction();
```

But the issue i am trying to target an element which is dynamically added in the DOM. When i viewsource the page i don't see this class in the code "onp-sl-signin-locker".

I get this error:
Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

It is because that element does not exist in the DOM. But i can see this class while using inspect element.

Can anyone help me with this please how can i get this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you'd call this function after adding the element to the DOM...

Comment: As David says, you call the function prior to element being added to the document.

Comment: If you have no control over when the element gets added, you'll have to resort to MutationObservers.

Comment: Yes! Exactly i don't over that element, it added by the plugin. Can you please show how can i MutationObservers? Thanks

Comment: You should always understand what you're using, so give it a ride: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Zain: It's probably worth also checking if the plugin you're using exposes the functionality you're looking for before trying to work around it with a MutationObvserver.